# Laravel 6: How can I use Group By within my view?

Tags: laravel, group-by, laravel-blade, laravel-6

I'm trying to group my products by SKU, but it's returning wrong values

**Controller:**

```
$pro = Product::groupBy('sku')->latest()->paginate(25);
```

**Blade**

```
@foreach ($pro as $sku => $p)
<p>{{$p['sku']}}</p>
<ul class="list-unstyled">
@foreach($p as $product)
<li><a href="{{route('admin.product.view',[$p['id']])}}">{{$p['name']}}</a></li>
@endforeach
</ul>
@endforeach
```

In the database I have these products registered:
[image: database]

However, it is returning multiple values to me

[image: Image of multiples values]

I need it to group it like this:

[image: Correct group]

Comment: What is the actual question? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Hello @BrianThompson Sorry for my English... I'm trying to group products by SKU [link](https://ibb.co/4sxs13J)  but I'm not able to return the grouped values correctly, for some reason it quadruples the values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might solve your problem:

```php
$skus = Product::latest()
    ->offset(0)
    ->limit(25)
    ->get()
    ->groupBy('sku');
```

In your view:

```php
@foreach ($skus as $sku => $products)
    <p>{{$sku}}</p>
    <ul class="list-unstyled">
        @foreach($products as $product)
            <li><a href="{{route('admin.product.view',[$product['id']])}}">{{$product['name']}}</a></li>
        @endforeach
    </ul>
@endforeach
```

Comment: Thank you very much, solved the problem. Only remove ] from {{$sku]}}

Comment: Good, I have fixed that.